# Web Page Print Preview

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing

I'm creating an online application form.
In front page, There are First Name, Last Name, Email etc... form inputs. What I want is that 
if user fills the form and click on the submit, I want to show him the print preview page with values which user filled... Is it possible? I'm using ASP.Net C#

Comment: I tried this, http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/rahul4_saxena/printing-in-Asp-Net/ but It wasn't what i actually, also I need have to save user information to Database... And send email to the user. etc... I've lot to do :(

Comment: Your requirement seem to fit into first step in any ASP.Net tutorial - fill out fields and than show values on a page after post back. It is unclear what exact problem you are facing (especially without any sample code).

Comment: I did it my own with NameValueCollection thing. I don't know what it is, but it has done my job :D Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

If you can use jquery this code is good

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
 window.print();
 });
```

and you can see these

http://www.designplace.org/tutorials.php?page=1&c_id=27

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/

https://web.archive.org/web/20211029043752/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/061103-1.shtml

Answer (score 0):

If you can use javascript, then try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function CallPrint(strid) {
    var prtContent = document.getElementById(strid);
    var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'letf=0,top=0,width=850,height=800,toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,status=0');
    WinPrint.document.write('<html><head><title>Popup</title>')
    WinPrint.document.write('</head><body>');
    WinPrint.document.write('</body></html>');
    WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML);
    WinPrint.document.close();
    WinPrint.focus();
    WinPrint.print();
        }
</script>
```

Take a print button on the page

```
<input id="btnPrint" type="button" value="Print" runat="server" 
    onclick="javascript:CallPrint('divPrint')"/>
```

and Place your Controls which are to be printed within a div

```
<div id="divPrint">
  //Your controls
</div>
```